# How to create a key.pem with RSA-PSS parameters in openssl that meet the PS256 requirements?

Tags: node.js, jwt, openssl, rsa, jose

#### Expected behavior of the correctly running application

I want to create a certificate, a key and a public key with [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) (3.2.1 30 Jan 2024). I need to sign this key and use it as a JWT token to get another access token via https request.

#### Environment

The application is written in TypeScript, which limits the choice of libraries for signing. I currently use [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose) and [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) packages, with the aim of signing the key correctly.

#### Problem

It seems that the message of the verify method of the jwt-package says that the key does not have the correct RSA-PSS parameters for the PS256 algorithm.

#### Requirements

The following requirements are placed on the creation of a certificate:

- Hash method: SHA-256
- Mask Generation Function: MGF1 with SHA-256
- Length of the salt: 32 bytes
- Trailer Field: 0xBC

---

To create the certificate, I executed the following commands with openssl to create cert.pem, key.pem and pubkey.pem.

###### Creating the certificate and key

```bash
openssl req -newkey rsa-pss -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

###### Extracting the public key

```bash
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

---

###### Imported via the file system, I sign the private key

Here it seems to work at first glance, but generates a token that does not appear to have a valid signature according to the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) debugger, as the test is not passed. This raises the question of whether client side rendering could be a problem. In any case, the results remain the same in Chrome and Firefox.

```js
const PS256 = 'PS256'
/**
 * Other const for SignJWT declared
 * ...
 */
const getSignedJWTToken = async () => {
    const privateKeyString = readFileSync(privateKeyPath, 'utf-8')
    const privateKey = await importPKCS8(privateKeyString, PS256)
    const signedJwt = await new SignJWT()
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: PS256 })
        .setIssuer(clientId)
        .setSubject(clientId)
        .setAudience(audienceUrl)
        .setIssuedAt(currentTime)
        .setExpirationTime(expirationTime)
        .setJti(uuid)
        .setNotBefore(notValidBeforeTime)
        .sign(privateKey)

    return signedJwt
}
```

###### Verify the signed token with jsonwebtoken verify method

Since jose gives no indication of a problem, I use the jsonwebtoken verify method to check whether the signed key can be verified with the key. The verification methods of jose provide a lot of information, but no indication of a successful signing.

```js
const logVerifcationOfSignedKey = async (signedJwt: string) => {
    const bufferKey: Buffer = fs.readFileSync(`${certPath}/key.pem`)
    jwt.verify(signedJwt, bufferKey, { algorithms: [PS256] }, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err)
            console.error('JWT verification failed:', err)
        else
            console.log('JWT verified successfully:', decoded)
    })
}
// Output: Error: Invalid key for this operation, its RSA-PSS parameters do not meet the
// requirements of "alg" PS256.
```

This is where the problem lies, which can apparently only be solved by using a different procedure when creating the key.

I was able to find a hint [here (accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905819/why-ec-key-is-treated-as-a-valid-rsa-key-for-the-jwt-and-jwk) regarding the `-keyout` option parameter. This should apparently create the key independently of the certificate. The alternative of using only the `-out` parameter was not a solution.

Does anyone have a clue or a solution that can help with this problem, or does anyone actually recognize the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The `jsonwebtoken` library does not implement the correct RSASSA-PSS parameters validation. It is missing a condition [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/lib/validateAsymmetricKey.js#L55-L57) for when there are no explicit parameters.

This condition is accounted for in the `jose` library [here](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/f23a29afc862c526527a90e73366ce5c0532fdf1/src/runtime/node/node_key.ts#L49-L56), that's why in Node.js you can sign and verify using your RSASSA-PSS key with `jose` but not with `jsonwebtoken`. A bug in `jsonwebtoken`.

As far as jwt.io goes, it uses `jose` under the covers but browser runtimes use [Web Cryptography API](https://w3c.github.io/webcrypto/) and it does not support the SPKI/PKCS#8 `id-RSASSA-PSS (1.2.840.113549.1.1.10)` structure. This affordance was [removed](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/pull/325) in 2022 to align the spec with what's interoperable between the different Web Cryptography API implementations.

For the best interoperability you should use the JSON Web Key format for everything, alternatively if you insist on using PEM serialized keys, use the plain old `rsaEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)` OID instead of `id-RSASSA-PSS (1.2.840.113549.1.1.10)` for RSA JWA algorithms.